# PHP Jquery Ajax loading php page and sending value with GET on already loaded php by jquery-ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm beginner in php jquery ajax and something confuses me.
I want to send data with GET function over jquery/Ajax

This is the code:

```
   <html>
     <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
                var number = 0;

               $('a.sumnumber').click(function(e) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    number += 1;
                    //alert('dfsdgsdgsg ' + number);
                    $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?sum=' + number);
               });

               $('a.minusnumber').click(function(e) {   
                    e.preventDefault();
                $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?minus=' + number);
               });
        });
          </script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <a href="#" class="sumnumber">+</a>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div class="sum">
            <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>
          </div>

     </body>
</html>
```

sum_number.php

```
<?php
      $sum = 0;
      if(isset($_GET['sum']))
      {

          $sum += $_GET['sum'];
          echo $sum;
      }



      echo '
            <br />
          <a href="#" class="minusnumber">-</a>
          <br />
      ';

      $minus = 100;
      if(isset($_GET['minus']))
      {

          $minus -= $_GET['minus'];
          echo $minus;
      }
?>
```

When i click on link with class sumnumber it works but when i click on link with class minusnumber that was loaded by jquery from sum_number.php nothing happen.
Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('a.minusnumber').live('click', function(e) {   
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?minus=' + number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load in minusnumber with javascript. You need to use bind or live on the click event.
Something like this. Dont forget to check the links too!

```
 $('a.minusnumber').click(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?minus=' + number);
    });
```

Sould be

```
$('a.minusnumber').live('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?minus=' + number);
});
```

or

```
  $('a.minusnumber').bind('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.sum').load('sum_number.php?minus=' + number);
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind 
http://api.jquery.com/live/